# How can I adapt my interface to all kind of devices (iOS/Android)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, responsive-design, grid, responsive

My UI looks different on both devices that I'm running my app on , which is normal , but I want to adapt it to both OS (iOS and Android) ,

I tried using StackLayout inside the Grids but nothing is changing , my UI is still not responsive .

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="interface_test.Login" BackgroundColor="#E7695C">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid BackgroundColor="#E7695C">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="0">
      </StackLayout>
      <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,0,20,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Source="arrow.png" HeightRequest="70" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="1" Placeholder="Email or Phone Number" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16"/>
        <Entry Grid.Row="2" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16" IsPassword="true"/>
        <Button Clicked="Handle_Clicked" Text="Log In" BackgroundColor="#2B3D4F" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="50"
                VerticalOptions="Start" Grid.Row="3" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="5">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Label BackgroundColor="#bababa" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center" />
          <!--<Label Text="" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>-->
          <Image Source="facebook.png" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
          <Label BackgroundColor="#bababa" Grid.Column="2" HeightRequest="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </Grid>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Grid.Row="6">
          <Label Text="Connectez-vous avec Facebook" TextColor="#2B3D4F"  />
        </StackLayout>
      </Grid>
      <StackLayout Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="#2B3D4F">
        <Label Text="Créer un compte" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
      </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

here's an example of what I got:

Android :

[image: Android Image]

iPhone :

[image: iOS Image]

And I would love if my Android interface will look as the iPhones's.

Comment: Just use the OnPlatform API for this may be? Something like this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47984/onplatform-xaml

Comment: Specifically what elements are you trying to get the same? If you're trying to get the Entires to have the same appearance on both platforms, you will need to set up a custom renderer of some kind.

Comment: could it work ?

Comment: actually , the problem that I had was only with my emulator , thanks anyways guys

Comment: So what effect do you want ? I thought you wanted Android to look like ios.

Answer (score 1):

you could use Custom Renderer to cutom the Control, for example(Entry):

1.custom **MyEntry** :

```
public class MyEntry :Entry
{
}
```

2.in ***.Android** create **MyEntryRenderer** :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace App11.Droid
{

   class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
     {
       public MyEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
         {
         }
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
         {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
              {
               // custom your style
               Control.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.edittext_shape);
              }
         }
     }
}
```

in **Resources/drawable** create the xml  (here called `edittext_shape`,which set the rounded corners of entry)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <solid android:color="#fff" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

3.use in **page's** **xaml** :

```
<ContentPage ...
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:*;assembly=*"
  ...>
  ...
  <local:MyEntry Placeholder="Email or Phone Number" PlaceholderColor="#bababa" FontSize="16"/>
  ...
</ContentPage>
```

More information can be found here:[CustomRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction)